# CSS-Border Problem - I have a border around an image. I also use margins on the image. Border doesn't fit tight against image?

Tags: image, xhtml, css, border

Quick question. Please see the example at http://www.urbanelementz.ca/ ...

The Image & Border I'm referring to is located on the top left of the main content area and has white text wrapping beside and below it.

Here's the URL to the image I'm talking about:

http://www.urbanelementz.ca/css/images/uelementz-index-colorefx1.png

I made the dotted border thicker and white so you can see what I'm talking about. I have a top margin and right margin set on the image so the text isn't right up against the image. How can I make the border go right up against (sit flush) with the image instead of around the image + the set margins. Without using padding as well if possible. I want to keep my margins set. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add/edit CSS with:

```css
img#colorfx1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: it's in line 147 in style.css.

Comment: I changed my css to this: img#colorfx1 { margin: 0px 5px 0px 1px; vertical-align: top; float: left; border-color: #FFF; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; }

Answer (score 3):

```css
img#colorfx1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 3px;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px 5px 0 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Change `padding` to `margin`, and it looks good.

I think you intended to write `margin` in the first place.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks everyone for all your help. It's been a long day and needed a fresh input from other fellow designers/coders. Thanks again!

Comment: I changed my css to this:

img#colorfx1 { 
margin: 0px 5px 0px 1px; 
vertical-align: top; 
float: left; 
border-color: #FFF; 
border-style: dotted; 
border-width: 1px; }

Answer (score 2):

I see this style applied:

```
img#colorfx1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 3px;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px 5px 0 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Removing the padding fixed it for me...

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the padding on the image. Set padding to 0:

```
img#colorfx1 { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Great comment - because it's not like the answers appeared after I clicked add post.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you don't have margin set to that image. You do have padding set to it though.
Once you remove padding and use margin instead it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set your css like this

```
img#colorfx1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  border: #FFFFFF dotted 3px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandding such as :

```
<img src="test.png" width="80" height="74" border="2" style="border-style:dotted; padding-left:5px">
```

this will appear same as what u want, here is some stuff also :
[link](http://css-tricks.com/622-using-css-for-image-borders/)

regards...

Answer (score 0):

I have a meta-answer: yes, padding was your problem.  You might be able to avoid asking this sort of question in the future if you start using a) Chrome's "Inspect Element" context menu command, or b) Firebug for Firefox, which is more or less the same thing.  Look at the element's calculated style and you can see exactly what property makes your element behave the way it does.

Comment: Yes I have firebug but it's been a long day and I just didn't think of it. Thanks though.